# How to reverse pairs in list without using `reverse`?

Tags: scheme

I have to write a function with the following input:

```
((something1 . something2) (something1 . something2) ... (something1 . something2))
```

and the corresponding output:

```
((something2 . something1) (something2 . something1) ... (something2 . something1))
```

I can't use `vector`, `for`, `while`, `set`, `reverse`, `set-list`, `list-tail`, `append`, `length`, or any procedure that ends with `!`.

I know this is wrong but maybe someone see where my mistake is:

```
(define (odwroc-alfabet list)
  (let loop ((list list))
    (if (pair? list)
        (cons ((cdar list) (caar list)))
        list)))
```

Comment: Did you even run it?  If so, how did it fail?

Comment: How `reverse` even work on a non-list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `map`:

```
(define (odwroc-alfabet lst)
  (map (lambda (e) (cons (cdr e) (car e))) lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to create the first swapped pair. You also need to recurse into the rest of the pairs and swap them too. Here's a modified version of your code:

```
(define (odwroc-alfabet list)
  (let loop ((list list))
    (if (pair? list)
        (cons (cons (cdar list) (caar list)) (loop (cdr list)))
        list)))
```

Of course, `loop` is a misnomer here since you're actually recursing rather than looping.

Comment: I'd argue against using `list` as a variable name at all (although it is used in the question), as it shadows the function of the same name.

Comment: Of course. In fact I usually use `lst` as the variable name, and I had to fight my motor memory to write `list` here. ;-)

Comment: `list` is good, actually exceptional.  Ingrains lexical scope in one lesson.

Comment: @GoZoner For learning, perhaps. But shadowing is often detrimental to code maintainability.

Comment: input: 
(define kod3 '((1 . #\n) (2 . #\p) (3 . #\n) (2 . #\z)))
(odwroc-alfabet kod3)
output:'((#\n . 1) (#\p . 2) (#\n . 3) (#\z . 2) . #<procedure:list>)

i don't know what is wrong ;< but version with map its good